# How can i change a url folder name to something else?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

Kindly change the From to To in the below:

From: http://localhost:8082/Test/Students/index

To: http://localhost:8082/Anything/Students/index

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this function**

> rename(old, new, context);

```
Eg.
<?php
    rename("images","pictures"); //change name of dir
    rename("/test/file1.txt","/home/docs/my_file.txt"); //change dir and file
?>
```